# Jenkins do not authenticate by SSH key on Git

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, jenkins, key-management

I've been trying to start a job on Jenkins to clone a repository by SSH Key but even after I setup the credentials I've keep getting a passphrase error.

*Sorry by portuguese prints.*

[image: Credentials]

[image: Creating a Job]

[image: Job setup]

[image: Console error]

I missed some setup configuration?

Thanks.

**WORKAROUND**
*I removed passphrase of public key and works. But still need a solution for encrypted passphrase.*

Comment: You need to establish a key-management policy.  Unattended processes typically use unencrypted keys.  Applying encryption to the private keys only shifts the problem one place over, as you now have to securely manage the passphrase.  The greatest risk of unencrypted keys is having them compromised; mitigate this by 1) restricting what Jenkins can do, and 2) change the jenkins/git keys on a regular basis or whenever you suspect they're compromised.

Comment: Ok but how I do it? Please give me details. Thanks @HenkLangeveld!